# Why can't I write to a file in the home directory?

Tags: vimscript, save

I want to write to a file in the home directory, so I tried the following command:

```
:call writefile(["foo"], "~/event.log", "a")
```

But I got an error:

```
E482: Can't create file ~/event.log
```

I am pretty sure that I have write permission for my home directory (of course), and there is not a file with the same name at the specified path.

If I change the destination path to the current path, it works.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for the commands you tried, but post them as text. This makes it easier to test them because the can be copied and pasted.

Comment: You might also like https://github.com/habamax/vim-godot although I didn't put ctags extension there (it is just in my .ctags)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tilde is only treated specially if it's used in commands like `:w ~/event.log`. When used in a string that is passed to a function -- even if this function treats the string argument as a file name -- it has no special meaning. You have to take care of the expansion of the tilde to the home directory yourself.

Vim has an `expand()` function that can be used for this. So one way to correctly write a file in your home directory is to execute the following command:

```
call writefile(["foo"], expand("~/event.log"), "a")
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for your answer and explanations.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You mean the example in the help file? That does not use a tilde.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer doh... this is why I prefer text 

Answer (score 6):

As Jürgen Krämer said, `'~'` string won't be interpreted by most vim functions.

Thus, when receiving the string from elsewhere, we may indeed need to `expand()` the tilde. However, when directly working on hardcoded pathnames as in your MWE, we can also use `$HOME` as in

```
call writefile(['foo'], $HOME.'/event.log'), 'a')
```